UIMenu from custom UIBarButtomItem
I am trying to present UIMenu from custom UIBarButtonItem on iOS13. I can't use iOS 14 API.
Problems are:

I need to show menu on tap, not on long tap(currently on long tap)
When menu is displayed my barButtonItem becomes white

This is my code:
class CollectionViewController: UIViewController, UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate {

private lazy var sizeMenu: UIMenu = { [unowned self] in
    return UIMenu(
        title: "Select size",
        image: nil,
        identifier: nil,
        options: [.displayInline],
        children: [
            UIAction(title: "Half", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.grid.2x2.fill"), handler: { _ in }),
            UIAction(title: "Third", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.grid.3x2.fill"), handler: { _ in }),
            UIAction(title: "Quarter", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.grid.4x3.fill"), handler: { _ in }),
        ]
    )
}()

func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
    return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { [unowned self] suggestedActions in
        return self.sizeMenu
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let customBarButtonItem = UIButton()
    customBarButtonItem.setTitle("edit", for: .normal)
    customBarButtonItem.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    let interaction = UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self)
    customBarButtonItem.addInteraction(interaction)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customBarButtonItem)
}
}




EDIT
I missed the iOS 13 comment in the question. As far as I know it's not possible to adjust the delay for the context menu (in iOS 13 or above). You can add a preview to your context menu by adding another delegate method:
func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, previewForHighlightingMenuWithConfiguration configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration) -> UITargetedPreview? {
    guard let view = interaction.view else { return nil }
    return UITargetedPreview(view: view)
}

You can adjust that view to your liking.
Original answer (iOS 14 and up)
From iOS 14 you can easily add a menu using the UIBarButtonItem(title:image:primaryAction:menu:). It's available from iOS 14 and up.
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let button = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Edit", menu: sizeMenu)
    button.tintColor = .white
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button
}

private lazy var sizeMenu: UIMenu = { [unowned self] in
    return UIMenu(
        title: "Select size",
        image: nil,
        identifier: nil,
        options: [.displayInline],
        children: [
            UIAction(title: "Half", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.grid.2x2.fill"), handler: { _ in }),
            UIAction(title: "Third", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.grid.3x2.fill"), handler: { _ in }),
            UIAction(title: "Quarter", image: UIImage(systemName: "square.grid.4x3.fill"), handler: { _ in }),
        ]
    )
}()

Or alternatively, if you want to use your custom view
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let customButton = UIButton()
    customButton.setTitle("Edit", for: .normal)
    customButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    customButton.menu = sizeMenu
    customButton.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customButton)
}

